# Audio/Video Recording and Rendering Using StageFright

Tags: android, stagefright

I am trying to develop video telephony application on Android. Hence I want to capture and render both the audio and video.

After some investigation, i think using the StageFright to this task, is better than using OpenMAX as it provides more hardware independence.

please let me know how the below tasks can be accomplished using StageFright,

1. Record the raw  video/audio from camera/microphone
2. Encode the raw video/audio
3. Decode the compressed video/audio
4. Play the uncompressed video/audio.

I guess the task 1 and 2 can be combined using the StageFright. Similarly task 3 and 4 can be combined too.

Any suggestions or ideas?

Comment: Hi Jairam :) if you have completed your tasks please share some code or ideas.I am also looking for Stagefright but so far I am not able to find any tutorial which can tell how to use it. Please Help :(

Comment: @AB1209 Hi, me to want to get started with, any help?

Comment: @nmxprime Check this https://github.com/appunite/AndroidFFmpeg.